# How to create custom bootloader with accompanying program loader for ATMega2560

Tags: arduino-mega, usb, bootloader, custom

Just for some context, I have created a custom board based on the ATMega2560. I currently have the original Arduino Bootloader for the ATMega2560 and have no problems uploading code via the USB Port on TX0 and RX0.

What I am hoping to achieve is creating a custom Bootloader that allows me to upload my .hex binaries to flash but in a proprietary way, so that any program cannot be uploaded to it with the standard **Wiring** Protocol used by Arduino IDE. In addition, I will need a custom PC based program that can upload the code via the USB port.

The reason why I need this is that I will have this device out in areas where I would not want someone taking the device and uploading their own program to it and screw it up. I know it sounds paranoid, however, it would be preferred to have this feature so I can update the firmware via the USB Port without using the **Wiring** protocol.

Has anyone accomplished this before?

## TL;DR

Want to upload custom Bootloader to Arduino Mega so that I can upload my firmware with a proprietary programmer via the USB Port on TX0 and RX0 because I am paranoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the bootloaders is publicly available, so a simple thing would be to make a minor modification, for example XOR each incoming byte with 0xEE. That would mean the bootloader wouldn't work with normal uploading programs (the IDE) but with a modified uploader.

However even simpler would be to upload your code using ICSP and **not include a bootloader at all**. Or, leave the bootloader there but turn off the BOOTRST fuse so that the processor ignores it.

That way, it takes some effort for people to replace your code.